# How to automatically resize nested TcxGroupBox

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using DevExpress 2012 controls to create a app that simulates the appeareance of a paper form to make easy data entry.

Each section of the form is a TcxGroupBox. And inside each of this TcxGoupBox can have many others TcxGroupBox on the same level and/or in nested levels.

They are all with TcxGroupBox.Align = alTop

However according to some parameters of the data some groups can be hidden, and that cause the other groups to align to top, that is correct.

My problem is how to automatically resize each TcxGroupBox botton border. When a group is hidden, all the groups in the same level get aligned to the top, and at the botton will -remain the space left of the hidden group. Its parent groups do not have an auto=resize attribute. The opposite is also true when it is needed to show back a hidden group and the parent group needs to be resized to accomodate it.

I am using Delphi XE2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the height property of each group boy accordingly. I guess this depends on the amount of checkable items and the column count. Using this approach has the advantage that all of your lines (i.e. checkable items) are aligned equally.

As much as I love the auto align possibilities I tend to set the size and position of such elements myself in the OnResize-Event of the bounding container (Panel, Group Box, Form, Frame).